# Is triple des Encryption /Decryption Support in sql server 2000?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2000

For Example:

Here, Is this function EncryptByPassPharase() support in sql server 2000? If Not Then is there any function like that in sql server 2000? How Can I do same thing in sql server 2000?

```
INSERT INTO  login_details(username,password) VALUES('smith2',EncryptByPassPhrase('12','XXX'))
```

Comment: 3DES should not be used for new work, the current standard symmetric encryption algorithm is AES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the function EncryptByPassPharase() is not support for SQL Server <  2008. On microsoft doc has been detail about it. You can se more detail here [ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql)

Comment: Thank You..Then What method should be use in sql server 2000 using triple des encryption?

Comment: this should be in comment @hong

Comment: Not sure, hope you can find some thing from here: http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/how-to-encrypt-a-column-in-sql-server-20002005/